# How can I succesfully re-write a file appending an element to a list using Common Lisp?

Tags: file, io, common-lisp

I want to write a Common Lisp list in a `.lisp` file. If the file does not exist, it will be created and add the element.

If the file already exists, it will re-write the file appending new content to the list.

This implementation partially works:

```lisp
(defun append-to-list-in-file (filename new-item &aux contents) ;;;;
  (setq contents (list)) ;; default in case reading fails
  (ignore-errors
    (with-open-file (str filename :direction :input)
      (setq contents (read str))))
  (setq contents (nconc contents (list new-item)))
  (with-open-file (str filename :direction :output :if-exists :overwrite)
    (write contents :stream str)))
```

If I do:

```lisp
(append-to-list-in-file  "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/CL.lisp" 4)
```

It works. The code creates the file AND puts `4` inside of it as `'(4)`. However, if I run the code again with a new element using the file that was just created:

```lisp
(append-to-list-in-file  "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/CL.lisp" 5)
```

It throws an error:

> Error opening #P"/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/CL.lisp"
> [Condition of type SB-EXT:FILE-EXISTS]

I was expecting: `'(4 5)`

What do I need to change?

Comment: there is a keyword `:if-exists` that you can use in `with-open` macro http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_open.htm#open . The value that you neet is probably `:overwrite` or `:append`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a good idea to create the file. Otherwise you can't overwrite it.

```
... :if-does-not-exist :create :if-exists :overwrite ...
```